# Comparing Array with more than one row

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to compare 2 Arrays and output the difference in a separate array.

I've made the following line of code to compare 2 Arrays;

```
$INPUTdifference = array_udiff($userINPUT, $iptablesINPUT, function ($userINPUT, $iptablesINPUT) { return (int) ($userINPUT != $iptablesINPUT); });
```

When `userINPUT` contains one row for testing, and `iptablesINPUT` a few, it works flawlessly.

However, whenever I add a second row in the userINPUT array, it completely stops working. It doesn't even give anything while I print the `INPUTdifference anymore`

What is wrong here?

EDIT;

The way userINPUT is acquired;

```
function getIPTablesINPUT() {


    /* ------------------------------ */
    // INPUT CHAIN
    /* ------------------------------ */



    $INPUTCOMMAND = popen('/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/iptables -L INPUT -nvx --line-numbers | tail -n +3', 'r');
    $INPUTcontent = '';
    while (!feof($INPUTCOMMAND)) {
        $INPUTcontent .= fread($INPUTCOMMAND, 4096);
    }
    pclose($INPUTCOMMAND);
    $INPUTlines = explode("\n", trim($INPUTcontent));
    $INPUTresults = array();
    $INPUTcounter = 0;


    foreach ($INPUTlines as $line) {


        $segments = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $line);


        $INPUTArray = array(
            'num' => $segments[0],
            'pkts' => $segments[1],
            'bytes' => $segments[2],
            'target' => $segments[3],
            'prot' => $segments[4],
            'opt' => $segments[5],
            'in' => $segments[6],
            'out' => $segments[7],
            'source' => $segments[8],
            'destination' => $segments[9]
        );


        array_push($INPUTresults, $INPUTArray);

        $INPUTcounter++;
    }

    return $INPUTresults;
}
```

then, outside of the function

```
$iptablesINPUT  = getIPTablesINPUT();
```

Then, the way the rules in the data

```
$dbconnection = pg_connect("host=x port=x dbname=x user=x password=xxxx") or die("Unable to connect to Postgres");


    // INPUT table from userDB
    $userINPUTresult = pg_query($dbconnection, "SELECT * FROM \"INPUT\"");
    if (pg_affected_rows($userINPUTresult) === 1) {

        $userINPUTArray = pg_fetch_all($userINPUTresult);
        echo "INPUT CHAIN RULES LOADED \n";
    } else {

        echo ("NO INPUT CHAIN RULES \n");
    }
```

==== VAR DUMPS ====

var_dump $iptablesINPUT

```
NULL
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(10) {
    ["num"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["pkts"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["bytes"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["target"]=>
    string(4) "DROP"
    ["prot"]=>
    string(3) "all"
    ["opt"]=>
    string(2) "--"
    ["in"]=>
    string(1) "*"
    ["out"]=>
    string(1) "*"
    ["source"]=>
    string(9) "192.0.0.1"
    ["destination"]=>
    string(9) "0.0.0.0/0"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(10) {
    ["num"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["pkts"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["bytes"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["target"]=>
    string(4) "DROP"
    ["prot"]=>
    string(3) "all"
    ["opt"]=>
    string(2) "--"
    ["in"]=>
    string(1) "*"
    ["out"]=>
    string(1) "*"
    ["source"]=>
    string(9) "192.0.0.2"
    ["destination"]=>
    string(9) "0.0.0.0/0"
  }
}
```

var_dump $userINPUT

```
NULL
```

Apparentely this is the spot where something goes wrong...

==== EDIT 2 ======

This is the way I extract the arrays from the function out of the scope.

```
// Slice up userDB arrays for comparing
$userINPUT = $allRules[0];
$userOUTPUT = $allRules[1];
$userFORWARD = $allRules[2];
$userPOSTROUTING = $allRules[3];
$userPREROUTING = $allRules[4];
```

Comment: Show full non-working code

Comment: The code you posted is ok

Comment: Made an edit with extra missing code

Comment: Print the result of `var_dump` for `$userINPUTArray` and `$iptablesINPUT` just before calling `array_udiff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `array_udiff` function returns you the elements which are in the first array and are not in the next arrays.

From [`array_udiff` page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php):

> array array_udiff ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ], callable $value_compare_func )
>
> Returns an array containing all the values of **array1** that are not present in any of the other arguments

Since the value of your first array (`$userINPUT` in your case) is `null` then the result of `array_udiff` will be also `null`.

Look, after execution of the following code

```
$a = array(1,2);
$b = array(1);
$c = array_udiff($a, $b, function($a, $b){return (int) $a != $b;});

// $c == array(2) now
```

the value of `$c` will be `array(2)`, since the following code

```
$a = null;
$b = array(1);
$c = array_udiff($a, $b, function($a, $b){return (int) $a != $b;});

// $c == null now
```

will lead to `$c` equals `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the function zavg, I understand the very principles of it now. However, the question here is **why** the $userINPUT is empty before it gets used in `array_diff`

Comment: That is another problem :) As I understand you take it from postgres, may be your query does not execute.

Comment: getIPTables() has the correct variable in his scope. However, I need to get that result array out of the scope and I do that by extracting  each entry of the array. I'll add the code, take a look.